# Is there a way to call a service when create task in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I want to implement a personal task manager, it supports managing tasks which create in TFS or create in the app manually. I want to know, is there away I can call a service when I create a User Story, Task or Bug in TFS? So that I can send the created items to the service, then pass to the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, via [service hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/get-started). Service hooks allow you to fire off JSON messages to REST endpoints when actions occur. There is a generic "[Web Hook](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/webhooks)" service hook, as well.